# Yahoo Pipes: Use custom address to render as rss

Tags: yahoo-pipes

I have several yahoo pipes that I have given custom addresses to (pipes.yahoo.com//) and I would like to be able to render this pipe as rss using the custom name I have assigned to it.

Obviously this isnt as easy as pipes.yahoo.com//pipe.run?_name&_render=rss.

For those of you out there, have you tried something like this and gotten it to work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up just writing a powershell script to update the feed webparts when needed.

Answer (score 0):

One nasty solution is to use the "XPath fetch page" module to grab the custom URL page, and extract the following XPath from the HTML:

```
//link[@type="application/rss+xml"]
```

Sadly even this doesn't give you an immediately usable URL - I needed to pass it through the "loop" operator to extract item.href and fetch the feed.

Working example at: http://pipes.yahoo.com/gavin_brock/get_pipe_by_custom_name

I also tried the "Find First Site Feed" module, which looked like it should do this in one, but it doesn't follow the redirects, unlike "XPath Fetch Page", so won't work (a bug in Pipes I think).